# How do I block specific websites in Google Search on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, blacklist

I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu and Google Search engine. There is an annoying habit where New York Times comes up first with news stories but when you click you can't read the stories because it is a paid subscription model (and I'm not paying).

I've found a Chrome extension for Google Search that will blacklist sites from search results:

- [How to Block Specific Websites from Google Search Results](https://www.wikihow.com/Block-Specific-Websites-from-Google-Search-Results)

However that is an extension for Google Chrome, not Firefox. Is there a Firefox extension for Google Search engine to blacklist annoying news sites that have "no news"? Or is there a way to configure Google Search engine without using the extension for Google Chrome? Alternatively is there a way for Firefox to blacklist certain sites and never visit them? Perhaps with a splash screen saying "blacklisted".

Comment: **Close Voters:** There are two votes recorded as off-topic because *"It does not appear to be about Ubuntu"*. Firefox is included in Ubuntu just as Bash is included in Ubuntu. Questions about how to add two numbers together in Bash or how to loop in Bash are on-topic. Therefore how to do something in Firefox which can be done in Google Chrome (which is not included in Ubuntu) is arguably on-topic. Additionally this question should be of interest to all Ubuntu users that have internet access.

Comment: VTLO: https://askubuntu.com/review/close/1015525

Comment: And even if it weren’t included in Ubuntu, “[r]unning third-party applications on Ubuntu” is clearly on-topic – VTLO.

Comment: This seems just seems like a low-effort and ranty question IMO.https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/personal-blocklist/ Also, I don't see the point of pointing out the users who voted to keep open/close either. YMMV

Comment: Sorry why is this a question? Took me 2 seconds: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/ublacklist/   It even has the same name for the extension and is from the same author. Seriously. This feels like trying to get attention to a plugin

Comment: @Rinzwind With 4 times the points you would be faster finding things :) Also the author's page has Danish in it which is your native tongue? But the biggest reason probably because is I have little experience with browser extensions / add-ons and internet configuration in general.

Comment: Nope Dutch ain't danish

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry common mistake of mine!